# fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 126 when trying to compile source code

Tags: dpkg

Using the instructions found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python), I have been trying to create source code from a python file using debhelper. I have reached the final step, where you have to enter:

```
$ debuild -us -uc
```

However, when I enter this command, I get the output:

```
/usr/bin/fakeroot: debian/rules: /usr/bin/make: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 126
```

How can I get this to compile correctly?

EDIT: Here are the contents of my debian/rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling `make` package

```
if dpkg -l | grep -q '^ii\s\+make\s'; then
    sudo apt-get --reinstall install make
else
    sudo apt-get install make
fi
```

Comment: Cheers, that fixed it. That's not a complicated code at all, is it :P

Answer (score 0):

If you have /usr/bin/make, then there is a typo on your debian/rules, perhaps you edited it using a windows editor and saved the filed with windows carriage returns ?

Try:

```
dos2unix debian/rules
```

Comment: I created everything using Ubuntu, so unfortunately this hasn't solved the issue.   How do I get /usr/bin/make, I installed everything in the tutorial and followed all the instructions and I don't seem to have one.    Also, I have added the contents of my debian/rules to the original post.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: build-essential is already the latest version. Yet I don't have /usr/bin/make?

Comment: There is very odd, run: sudo apt-get install --reinstall make

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was builing on a filesystem that was mounted noexec.

To test this from a shell:

```
( echo '#!/bin/sh' ; echo echo You can run executables on this fs ) > t.sh
chmod +x t.sh
./t.sh
```

If you don't get a permission denied error, then that's not your problem. If you do, then you either need to remount the fs without the noexec option or do your work somewhere else.